# How to trigger a download handler from a custom button in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app. The app contains a table. Each row in the table contains one button that should allow a user to download the data from that row into a report.

I am simply stuck on being able to hook the custom row button to the download handler. Normally I'd use the download button to do this but how can I do it with a custom button.

My observe event:

```
observeEvent(input$lastClick,
               {
                 if (input$lastClickId%like%"letter")
                 {
                   row_to_report=as.numeric(gsub("letter_","",input$lastClickId))
                   MyLetter=RV4$data[row_to_report,]
```

## How do I trigger the download here using the downloadHandler:

```
                 downloadHandler(
                 filename = "letter.docx",
                 content = function(file) {
                   tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "letter.Rmd")
                   file.copy("letter.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

                   # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
                   params <- list(MyLetter)

                   rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                                     params = params,
                                     envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()),

                   )
                 }
               )
             }
             else if (input$lastClickId%like%"delete")
             {
               row_to_del=as.numeric(gsub("delete_","",input$lastClickId))
               RV3$data=RV3$data[-row_to_del,]
             }
           }
```

)

My datatable is created like this:

```
  output$drilldownBarr <- DT::renderDT({

      if (!is.null(drilldataBarrd())) {  

        browser()
        drilldataBarrdf<-drilldataBarrd()
        drilldataBarrdf$Actions<-
         paste0('
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary letter" id=letter_',1:nrow(drilldataBarrd()),'>Letter</button>
                </div>
                ')
     }

    datatable(drilldataBarrdf,escape=F, extensions = c("Select","Buttons"), selection = "none",

              options = list(
                scrollX = TRUE,
                scrollY = TRUE,
                pageLength = 200,
                select = "api",
                dom = 'Bfrtip',
                buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print','colvis'))
    )
  })
```

Perhaps there is a better way? For example creating a download button in each row. But how to do this?

Comment: How do you do this table ? With `DT` you can put some `downloadButton`s in a column.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I have shown how I create the datatable. I guess I dont know how to create the download button in each row. And once this is done how to associate the download button with the data from just that row?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using base64 encoding of the report file. It does not use `downloadHandler`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(base64enc)
library(rmarkdown)

js <- '
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("download", function(b64){
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.append(a);
  a.download = "report.docx";
  a.href = b64;
  a.click();
  a.remove();
})
'

buttonHTML <- function(i){
  as.character(
    actionButton(
      paste0("button_", i), label = "Report", 
      onclick = sprintf("Shiny.setInputValue('button', %d);", i)           
    )
  )
}

dat <- iris[1:5,]
dat$Action <- sapply(1:nrow(dat), buttonHTML)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, escape = -ncol(dat)-1)
  })

  observeEvent(input[["button"]], {
    showNotification("Creating report...", type = "message")
    tmpReport <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")
    file.copy("report.Rmd", tmpReport)
    outfile <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.docx")
    render(tmpReport, output_file = outfile, 
           params = list(data = dat[input[["button"]], -ncol(dat)]))
    b64 <- dataURI(
      file = outfile, 
      mime = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    )
    session$sendCustomMessage("download", b64)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The `rmarkdown` file **report.Rmd**:

````markdown
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Stéphane Laurent"
date: "16 avril 2020"
output: word_document
params:
  data: "x"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
params$data
```
````

Comment: Thank you @StéphaneLaurent. Your solution works fine until the final dialogue box that asks where I want to download to. It then just gives me an empty download with 'Failed - Download error' but no error in the console. I have tried running the app in the browser as well but with the same result. I even emptied the mime but still the same.

Comment: @SebastianZeki Have you tried with my example (including my file `report.Rmd`)? For me it works fine.

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent. Yes I did try your example. Maybe it is a browser issue. I am using chrome. Is there a known issue with this mime type and chrome? Which browser are you using?

Comment: @SebastianZeki I'm using Chrome as well.

Comment: My apologies @StéphaneLaurent, I had some kind of anti-virus software running that was scuppering my downloads. It works perfectly. Thanks